# TLS: Client Hello and Server Hello are TLSv.1.2 but negotiated version is TLSv.1.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tls1.3

I am currently SSL-Debugging my Java 17 Spring Boot Application and I found some weird occurence regarding the SSL logs.

```
First, I get the 'Client Hello' with 'client version: TLSv1.2'.
Then, I get the the log 'Negotiated Protocol version: TLSv.1.3
Finally, I get the 'Server Hello', but this server hello has also the 
entry 'server version: TLSv1.2'.
```

Should the server version not be TLSv1.3 after the negotation process?

Comment: *"Should the server version not be TLSv1.3 after the negotation process?"* - no. The version of the record layer stays at TLS 1.2 for compatibility reasons. For details see the standard.

Comment: Ok, but why do I get the log ''Negotiated Protocol version: TLSv.1.3'  ? Its a message in between of Client Hello and  Server Hello.

Comment: See the supported_version extension in ServerHello. That's how it works in TLS 1.3